# Why am I getting Step implementation missing for: error when there is step implementation?

Tags: regex, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am doing e2e testing with Cypress `version 10.9.0` and using [this cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor)

```js
Given('I am at the portal login page', () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env("newPortalWeb_login"), { timeout: 100000 });
})

When('I enter an invalid username on the login page', () => {
    cy.get('#username').type('portal').invoke('removeAttr', 'value').click({ force: true }, { timeout: 30000 })
    cy.get('#password').type('SwY66bc3VZLUFR9')
    cy.get('[type="submit"]').click()
})

Then('an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username/password', () => {
    cy.get(".invalid").should('contain.text', 'Invalid username/password')
})

When('I enter an invalid password on the login page', () => {
    cy.get('#username').type('portaluser')
    cy.get('#password').type('Srntrhn$')
    cy.get('[type="submit"]').click()
})
```

```
Feature: Login

    Scenario: #1 Test Invalid Username / Invalid Password / Empty Username / Valid Username and Empty Password
        Given I am at the portal login page
        When I enter an invalid username on the login page
        Then an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username/password
        When I enter an invalid password on the login page
        Then an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username/password
        When I enter a valid username with an empty password on the login page
        Then an error message is displayed with the text Please enter your password
        When I enter an empty username with a valid password on the login page
        Then an error message is displayed with the text Please enter your username
        When I enter an empty username with an empty password on the login page
        Then an error message is displayed with the text Please enter your username
        And an error message is displayed with the text Please enter your password
```

There is step implementation but still getting the error that says step impl is missing. Can someone assist me please? Thank you
[image: SS of Cypress Error]

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/` between `username/password`? or at least escaping it in both the `spec` & `feature` file?

Comment: Also, this https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/722

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the `/` character in your step file like so `\/`.

That also means using a regular expression rather than a string, like this:
`/an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username\/password/`

```js
Given('I am at the portal login page', () => {

})

When('I enter an invalid username on the login page', () => {

})

Then(/an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username\/password/, () => {
  // matches you feature description
})
```

Comment: Hi @NicholaWalker, `/` was my issue that I figured yesterday. So, you're right. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same problem, until I paid closer attention to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's the problem but this line looks problematic

```
cy.get('#username').type('portal').invoke('removeAttr', 'value')
.click({ force: true }, { timeout: 30000 })
```

You should change it to this:

```
cy.get('#username').type('portal').invoke('removeAttr', 'value')
.click({ force: true, timeout: 30000 })
```